# Create Windows Share shortcut

Tags: 12.10, windows, shared-folders

I can easily connect to a windows share with the follow path on my Windows machine by using the Dash Home search function:

smb://dextrousdave-pc/users/DextrousDave/Google%20Drive

Now problem is, i need to type in this command every time or navigate via the 'Browse Network' icon in nautilus...Which is tedious. How can I create a shortcut in nautilus for the folder : users/DextrousDave/Google%20Drive ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please put it as as answer, so I can give you some points and mark it solved...Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to the **Windows Share** in Nautilus using one of the ways described in the question. Nautilus is what you get when you click on the folder icon on the left.

While the Nautilus Windows Share being the active window, mouse over to the top panel to get to **Menu > Bookmark > Add Bookmark** The new Bookmark will appear on the left panel of Nautilus.

Hope this helps